# In $N(T)$, how can we take $T$ to $\infty$?

Tags: analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Consider a rectangle with vertices $2+iT$, $2-iT$, $-1+iT$ and $-1-iT$ where $T>3$ is not an ordinate of zero of Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$. Then if $N(T)$ is the number of zeros of the Riemann zeta function upto height $T$, then in The Theory of Hardy's Z function by Aleksandar Ivic pg. 10-11 we have $$N(T)=\frac{T}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{T}{2\pi}\right)-\frac{T}{2\pi}+\frac{7}{8}+\mathcal{O}(\log T)$$

So we have $$\lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{N(T)}{ \frac{T}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{T}{2\pi}\right)-\frac{T}{2\pi}  }=1 $$

**Question:** How can we take the limit as $T$ goes to $\infty$? Is $T$ arbitrary? If yes then how can we consider a rectangle with arbitrary height?

Answer (score 1):

T is not COMPLETELY "arbitrary" as we require that "T> 3" but other than that, yes, T is a variable and can take any value greater than 3.

Comment: Thanks. But if $T>3$ is a variable, and we have a rectangle with height $T>3$ then is that rectangle a variable rectangle? Is the revtangle not fixed? Please elaborate

Comment: @Kim of course it is a variable rectangle, as its height $T$ grows with $T$. The width is fixed.  Have you ever computed an integral on the real line using the residue theorem? If so, those are typically done with figures like rectangles or semicircles (with diameter) of increasing size.  It's the same as that.

Comment: I would say, not that we have  a "variable rectangle", but that we have infinitely many rectangles with different values of T.

Comment: @KCd Thanks. So in this question where width is not fixed, can we take $H$ tends to $\infty$? See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527963/zeros-of-entire-function-on-a-rectangle

Comment: @GeorgeIvey Thanks. So in this question where width is not fixed, can we take $H$ tends to $\infty$? See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527963/zeros-of-entire-function-on-a-rectangle